# sklearn fit_transform() CopyWarning : A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have read numerous posts about this error. I wasn't able to produce a solution that solved my issue. Below are three attempts at solving the issue. They all produce CopyWarning.

```
ordinal = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['F','E','D','C','B','A']])

X['merchant_category'] = ordinal.fit_transform(X[['merchant_category']])
X.loc[:, 'merchant_category'] = ordinal.fit_transform(X[['merchant_category']])
X.loc[:, 'merchant_category'] = ordinal.fit_transform(X.loc[:, ['merchant_category']])
```

I have tried to use the 3 different variation above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is from before this part of your code. Since X is a copy of a dataframe you must have done something like this before:

```
X = X[['merchant_category']]
```

You can either correct this issue in your code before, or start your code here with:

```
X = X.copy()
```

This will set X as a new independent dataframe.